# Erro: Exception in thread "main" - StackOverflowError

Tags: java

Criei um CRUD de uma biblioteca, porém quando instanciei a classe `Biblioteca` no `main`, e fui executar ocorreu esse erro gigante:

[image: StackOverflowError]

**Classe `Cadastrar`:**

```
package Operacoes;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import Entidades.Autor;
import Entidades.Editora;
import Entidades.Livro;
import RepositorioLivros.Biblioteca;

public class Cadastrar {
    Scanner scannerNumerico = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scannerString = new Scanner(System.in);  
    Biblioteca biblioteca= new Biblioteca();

        //Autor
        public void cadastrarAutor(){

            try{
               Autor autor= new Autor();

              System.out.println("Digite o nome:");
              autor.setNome(scannerString.nextLine());  

              System.out.println("Digite o nacionalidade:");
              autor.setNacionalidade(scannerString.nextLine()); 

              System.out.println("Digite o codigo:");
              autor.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());  

              System.out.println("Digite o email:");
              autor.setEmail(scannerString.nextLine()); 

              biblioteca.cadastarAutor(autor);

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error: Algum dado não foi digitado corretamente");
            }

        }


        //Editora
        public void cadastrarEditora(){


            try{
                Editora editora= new Editora();

                System.out.println("Digite o nome:");
                editora.setNome(scannerString.nextLine());


                System.out.println("Digite o código:");
                editora.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());


                System.out.println("Digite o CNPJ:");
                editora.setCnpj(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

                biblioteca.cadastrarEditora(editora);

                }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println("Error: Algum dado não foi digitado corretamente");
                }
            }


        //Livro
        public void cadastrarLivro(){
            try{
                Livro livro= new Livro();

                System.out.println("Digite o nome do livro:");
                livro.setNome(scannerString.nextLine());

                System.out.println("Digite o código do livro:");
                livro.setCodigo(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Digite o ano do livro:");
                livro.setAno(scannerNumerico.nextInt());

                System.out.println("Forneça a editora do livro:");
                livro.setEditora(scannerString.nextLine());

                biblioteca.cadastrarLivro(livro);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: Algum dado não digitado corretamente");
                }

        }


        //Menu com as opções
        public void escolherOpcao(){

            int opc=0;

            System.out.println("-====== MENU: CADASTRAR ======-\n\n" +
                    "1) Cadastrar autor \n" +
                    "2) Cadastar Editora \n" +
                    "3) Cadastrar Livro\n"+
                    "4) Voltar"+
                    "5) Sair");


            boolean flag = true;


            while(flag){
                /*Enquanto a flag for verdadeira, ou seja, quando houver erro,
                o while irá repetir a opção pro usuário digitar novamente*/

                System.out.println("Digite a opção desejada:");


            try{
                opc=scannerNumerico.nextInt();
                flag = false; 
                // quando Ñ houver erro a flag vai ser falsa, e o programa segue normalmente


            }catch(InputMismatchException e){

                  System.out.println("Error: Só pode digitar números inteiros de  1 a 5");

         }
            }


            switch(opc){

            case 1:{
                this.cadastrarAutor();
            break;

            }


            case 2:{
                this.cadastrarEditora();
            break;

            }


            case 3:{
                this.cadastrarLivro();
            break;
            }

            //voltar ao menu
            case 4:{
                break;
            }


            case 5:{
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }

            default:{
                break;
            }

        }//chave do Switch
        }//chave do método do menu

}
```

**Classe `Biblioteca`:**

```
package RepositorioLivros;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import Entidades.Autor;
import Entidades.Editora;
import Entidades.Livro;
import Operacoes.Cadastrar;
import Operacoes.Editar;
import Operacoes.Excluir;
import Operacoes.ExcluirTudo;
import Operacoes.Listar;
import Operacoes.Pesquisar;


    public class Biblioteca {

        Scanner scannerNumerico = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scannerString = new Scanner(System.in);  


        //Instância das classes das operações
        Cadastrar cadastro=new Cadastrar();
        Editar editar=new Editar();
        Pesquisar pesquisar=new Pesquisar();
        Listar listar=new Listar();
        Excluir excluir=new Excluir();
        ExcluirTudo excluirTudo=new ExcluirTudo();


        String result;



        // Array list das entidades

        ArrayList <Autor> autores= new ArrayList<Autor>();
        ArrayList<Editora> editora= new ArrayList<Editora>();
        ArrayList<Livro> livro= new ArrayList<Livro>();


        //Menus
        public void Menu() {
        int opc=0;

        System.out.println("-======MENU======-\n\n" +
                "1. Cadastrar\n" +
                "2. Editar\n" +
                "3. Pesquisar\n" +
                "4. Listar\n" +
                "5. Excluir\n" +
                "6. Excluir tudo\n" +
                "7. Sair");

        boolean flag=true;

        while(flag){
            System.out.println("Digite a opção desejada:");


            try{
                opc=scannerNumerico.nextInt();
                flag=false;

            }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Só pode digitar números inteiros de  1 a 7");

            }

        }


        switch(opc){

        //Opções de cadastro
        case 1:{
            cadastro.escolherOpcao();
            break;
       }

        //Opções de editar
        case 2:{
            editar.Menu();
            break;
        }

        //Opções de pesquisar
        case 3:{
             pesquisar.Menu();
             break;
        }


        //Opções de listar
        case 4:{
            listar.Menu();
            break;
        }


        //Opções de excluir
        case 5:{
            excluir.menu();
            break;
        }


        //Opções de excluir tudo
        case 6:{
            excluirTudo.Menu();
            break;
        }


        //Sair
        case 7:{
            System.out.println("Obrigado por usar meu sistema !");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }

        default:{
            break;
        }

    }

}




        //Autores

        public void cadastarAutor(Autor autor) {
            this.autores.add(autor); 
        }


        public String ListarAutores() {


            for(int i=0; i<autores.size(); i++){

            result="Código:"+autores.get(i).getCodigo()+
            "\nNome:"+autores.get(i).getNome()+
            "\nNacionalidade"+autores.get(i).getNacionalidade()+
            "\nEmail:"+autores.get(i).getEmail();

            }

            return result;
        }



        public Autor pesquisarAutor(int codigo) {

            for(int i=0; i<autores.size(); i++){

            if(autores.get(i).getCodigo()==codigo)
            return autores.get(i);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


        public void removerAutorAnterior(Autor codigo) {

            autores.remove(codigo);
        }



        public void removerTodosAtores() {
            autores.clear();

        }





        //Editora

        public void cadastrarEditora(Editora editora) {
            this.editora.add(editora);

        }


        public String listarEditora() {

            for(int i=0; i<editora.size(); i++){
                result="Nome\n"+editora.get(i).getNome()+
                "\nCNPJ"+editora.get(i).getCnpj()+
                "\nCódigo"+editora.get(i).getCodigo();
            }


            return result;
        }


        public Editora pesquisarEditora(int codigo) {

            for(int i=0; i<editora.size(); i++){

                if(editora.get(i).getCodigo()==codigo){
                    editora.get(i);

                }

            }
            return null;
        }



        public void removerEditoraAnterior(Editora codigo) {

         editora.remove(codigo);
        }


        public void removerTodasEditoras() {
            editora.clear();

        }





        //Livro

        public void cadastrarLivro(Livro livro) {
            this.livro.add(livro);
        }



        public String listarLivro() {
            for(int i=0; i<livro.size(); i++){

                result= "Nome:\n"+livro.get(i).getNome()+
                        "Código:"+livro.get(i).getCodigo()+
                        "\nAno:"+livro.get(i).getAno()+
                        "Editora:"+livro.get(i).getEditora();


            }

            return result;
        }


        public Livro pesquisarLivro(int codigo) {

            for(int i=0; i<livro.size(); i++){

                if(livro.get(i).getCodigo()==codigo){
                    livro.get(i);

                }

            }


            return null;
        }


        public void revomerLivroAnterior(Livro codigo) {
            this.livro.remove(codigo);


        }


        public void removerTodosLivros() {
            livro.clear();

        }


}
```

Irei colocar o código completo no meu GitHub, pois é muito grande:
https://github.com/ViniciusStark/Codes

Olhem primeiro a classe `Biblioteca` e a classe `Cadastrar`, acho deve ter alguma coisa errada em uma das duas.

Answer (score 0):

Quem veio primeiro? O ovo ou a galinha?

Olhe isso:

```
public class Cadastrar {
    Biblioteca biblioteca= new Biblioteca();
}

public class Biblioteca {
    //Instância das classes das operações
    Cadastrar cadastro=new Cadastrar();
}
```

E então, ao criar uma instância de `Cadastrar`, uma nova instância de `Biblioteca` é criada e colocada no atributo `biblioteca`. Porém, ao criar uma nova instância de `Biblioteca`, uma outra instância de `Cadastrar` é criada e colocada no atributos `cadastro`.

Bem, para instanciar uma `Biblioteca` você instancia um `Cadastrar`, que por sua vez ao ser instanciado, instancia uma outra `Biblioteca`, que ao ser instanciada, instancia um outro `Cadastrar`, que ao ser instanciado, instancia uma outra `Biblioteca`, que ao ser instanciada, instancia um outro `Cadastrar`, que ao ser instanciado, instancia uma outra `Biblioteca` [...]

... E assim seria para todo o sempre e por toda a eternidade se não fosse o fato de que a pilha de execução é finita e os construtores vão se entulhando nela cada vez mais. Uma hora, a pilha de execução enche tanto que ela explode. O nome dessa explosão é `StackOverflowError`.

Desculpe a sinceridade, mas o seu código está muito ruim e cheio de problemas. Para arrumar todos os problemas, teria que praticamente reescrever do zero. Portanto, vou me limitar a resolver apenas o do `StackOverflowError`. Há várias formas de se resolver isso, mas a primeira solução que vejo neste caso é trabalhar com construtores:

```
public class Cadastrar {

    private Biblioteca biblioteca;

    public Cadastrar(Biblioteca biblioteca) {
        this.biblioteca = biblioteca;
    }
}

public class Biblioteca {
    //Instância das classes das operações
    Cadastrar cadastro = new Cadastrar(this);
}
```

Nesta solução, você elimina o problema do ovo e da galinha ao deixar bem claro quem é que vem primeiro. O objeto `Biblioteca` vem primeiro e o `Cadastrar` é criado com base em uma `Biblioteca` já existente ao invés dele criar uma nova. O objeto `Biblioteca` é responsável por criar o `Cadastrar` informando a si mesmo como a `Biblioteca` já existente.

A segunda solução é usar singletons:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    public static final INSTANCIA = new Biblioteca();

    private Biblioteca() {
    }
}

public class Cadastrar {
    public static final INSTANCIA = new Cadastrar();

    private Cadastrar() {
    }
}
```

E então, na classe `Biblioteca`, ao invés de usar o atributo `cadastro`, use `Cadastrar.INSTANCIA`. Na classe `Cadastrar`, ao invés de usar o atributo `biblioteca`, use `Biblioteca.INSTANCIA`. Nesta solução, apenas uma instância estática de cada é criada e elas se referenciam mutuamente apenas quando uma precisar da outra.

Comment: Ok amigo, como eu disse sou iniciante, acho que eu etenderia melhor se vc me mostrasse a sua solução implementada dentro do meu código, não teria como mostrar a primeira solução que vc disse implementada dentro da classe Cadastrar?, agradeceria muito